# Proper way of handling multiple cases

Tags: php

I have a method that can return 3 different cases

```
public function check_verification_status($user_id) {

        global $db;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` 
                WHERE `id` = ".clean($user_id)." 
                AND `type_id` = 1";
        $result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

        $list = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if ($list['verification_key'] == '' && !$list['verified']) {

            //No key or verified    
            return 0;

        } elseif ($list['verification_key'] != '' && !$list['verified']) {

            //key exists but not verified = email sent  
            return 2;

        } elseif ($list['verification_key'] != '' && $list['verified']) {

            //verified
            return 1;

        }

    }
```

A form / message is output depending on the return value from this

I would have used bool for return values when comparing 2 cases, what is the proper way of handling more than 2 cases and what would the ideal return value be.

The way i call this:

```
$v_status = $ver->check_verification_status($user_id);

if ($v_status === 0) {
 //do something 
} elseif ($v_status === 1) {
 //do something else
} elseif ($v_status === 2) {
 //do something totally different
}
```

I want to learn the right way of handling such cases as I run into them often.

note: I know I need to upgrage to mysqli or PDO, its coming soon

Comment: If you have working code and would like feedback on it, consider asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @kojiro thankyou for that - I was not aware of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is fine, but you can also use a switch statement:

```
$v_status = $ver->check_verification_status($user_id);

switch ($v_status) {

    case 0: {
     //do something 
     break;
    } 
    case 1: {
     //do something else
     break;
    } 
    case 2: {
     //do something totally different
     break;
    }
}
```

Comment: However, PHP `switch/case` expressions do type-loose comparisons, so this is not equivalent to OP's expressions using `===`.